# Symfony2 best practice with "div layers" form(s)

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, symfony-forms, layer

As a newbie in Symfony2 I have the following question:

In my project I have mostly an overview-page with the need to add/edit/delete entries. There is the demand to show always the overview-page and to do the add/edit/delete actions in "div-layers" (and to refresh the overview-page just after action). The overview pages have a form to search for entries and the customer just wants to keep these (search- & result) entries after any actions....

Any suggestions how to solve this with best practice in Symfony?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this question is unclear and has no relation to Symfony. You can generate your templates as you wish. And if you are searching best practices of Symfony, look this article http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those how have similar problem have a look at the bootstrap framework. Dokumentation can be found at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

This gave me all necessary information to start...